# Tooltip in Paper.js

Tags: paperjs

I am a beginner in Paper.js . Please could someone tell me how to display tool tip on a paper.js object ? The tool tip should be visible when the mouse moves over the object and should disappear when the mouse moves away from the object .

Thank you.

Comment: can someone please answer this.. I am stuck here :(

Answer (score 2):

When drawing your object you want to create a popup for, first add it to a group, then use the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave handlers on that object:

```js
// Create a group
var group = new Group();
// Create a dot (circle the mouse will hover)
var point = new Point(50, 50);
var dot = new Path.Circle(point, 5);
dot.fillColor = 'blue';
// Add dot to group
group.addChild(dot);

// Create onMouseEnter event for dot
dot.onMouseEnter = function(event) {
  // Layout the tooltip above the dot
  var tooltipRect = new Rectangle(this.position + new Point(-20, -40), new Size(40, 28));
  // Create tooltip from rectangle
  var tooltip = new Path.Rectangle(tooltipRect);
  tooltip.fillColor = 'white';
  tooltip.strokeColor = 'black';
  // Name the tooltip so we can retrieve it later
  tooltip.name = 'tooltip';
  // Add the tooltip to the parent (group)
  this.parent.addChild(tooltip);
}

// Create onMouseLeave event for dot
dot.onMouseLeave = function(event) {
  // We retrieve the tooltip from its name in the parent node (group) then remove it
  this.parent.children['tooltip'].remove();
}
```

Comment: I think as long as your tip has no words in it, this works fine.